# What is special about an ETF that is "not an investment company" under the 1940 Act, and what is important to keep in mind when buying such an ETF?

Tags: united-states, stocks, etf

I am very interested in trading [UVXY](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSEARCA:UVXY) and would like to know a little bit more about it. I read the document on the [ProShare website](http://www.proshares.com/funds/uvxy.html) but it does not make much sense to me, and I just hope someone can answer a few basic questions for me.

What does this mean?

> This fund is not an investment company regulated under the Investment
>   Company Act of 1940 and is not afforded its protections.

What happens if ProShare decided to delist this ETF?

Anything else you think is important to know to trade this ETF?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trading something you don't understand.  Read the prospectus and do a lot of research on the things you don't know until you do know.  Then you can trade (I still wouldn't though..but that's a different topic).

Comment: With a -90.72% return since inception... BEWARE! :-)

Comment: @PeterK. - its a 2x leveraged vehicle, those are always going to lose over long term. They are very short term investments.

Comment: Are you an expert on the short term futures market for S&P 500 companies? If not, then stay away, far far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this mean?
>
> > This fund is not an investment company regulated under the Investment Company Act of 1940 and is not afforded its protections.

That the fund isn't a traditional open-end mutual fund, unit investment trust or closed-end fund. The [1940 Investment Company Act](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/investmentcompanyact.asp) as noted on Investopedia was created after the crash of 1929 to regulate these instruments.

> What happens if ProShare decided to delist this ETF?

I'd presume shareholders would get the proceeds from the liquidation of the fund, though delisting isn't likely though reverse splits would be my caution as if the price gets low enough some exchanges may request companies do reverse splits that can annoy some people.

> Anything else you think is important to know to trade this ETF?

Yes, understand what strategy you have around trading this ETF in terms of getting in and out as it could be quite a volatile holding looking at its graph.